# validates_inclusion_of failing for unknown reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :body, :date_time, :excerpt, :permalink, :title, :premium, :status
    before_create :set_defaults
    validates_inclusion_of :status , :in => %w(draft pending published) , :allow_blank => false

    def set_defaults
        self.status ||= 'draft'
    end
end
```

However when I go to create one like this:

```
article = Article.new( {
            "title" => "test",
            "body" => "test" ,
            "excerpt" => "test"
            } )

article.save
```

It fails and provides the error:

```
[:status, "is not included in the list"]
```

I'm trying to figure out why a default is not being set.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `before_validation :set_defaults , :on => :create`, validations run and then before create callbacks.

Comment: That works, although in the later version of rails it's like this: `before_validation :set_defaults , :on => :create`.  Also, I just tried `after_initialize` which works as well.  I wonder which one is a better approach.

Comment: I'll mark it correct if you can change it to `before_validation :set_defaults , :on => :create`

Comment: Last I checked after_initialize had some performance implications so I generally avoid it if I can, however it is plausible that at some point an object could be created and saved without validation which would skip your defaulting.  The best approach seems to me to be pretty dependent on your app and tolerances.